# Why does my water turn into a cube at the end of the simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm new to blender, I'm trying to learn water simulation, but after the end of the flow it turns into its domain shape. Why and how solve this?

Comment: Could you upload your .blend to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit your question to include the link given to you once the upload is complete, or at the very least include some screenshots of your setup, especially the settings for the domain and flow objects.

Comment: It could be just accordance of the end frames of the fluid simulation and whole animation. If you set end frame of fluid sim to be 250 (default), then past frame 250 you'll see domain shape.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your solution worked cool!

Answer (score 2):

There can be several reasons to this.

1. If there is no fluid in the domain (possibly because of an outflow), it will display the domain mesh.
2. The simulation is not baked to the last frame of the scene. Once a simulation is baked (it uses the scenes start and end frame) it stops at that frame. Increasing the end frame would result in some unsimulated frames, the simulation has to be run again.
3. The fluid particles may be too small or too few in the domain. When the fluid falls below the minimum size (specified by the simulation resolution), it display the domain mesh. If you have many tiny drops, which you want to simulate, you need to increase the resolution.

The solution is to hide the domain in the viewport and in the render.
To hide the domain mesh from the last simulated frame onwards, animate the **Restrict Render** and **Restrict Viewport visibility**. This way, you can hide the domain mesh on certain frames.

[image]

**Step 1**: Go a frame where domain is still simulated. Hover over the *Restrict Render* property in the outliner and press *I* to set a keyframe. (Same with the *Restrict Viewport visibility* property.)

**Step 2**: Go to the first frame, from which on you want to hide the domain.  Disable *Restrict Render* and *Restrict Viewport visibility* and keyframe them again.

Comment: Sure, the solution is fine, but the reason for the problem is a bit overly complicated in general. Most of the times where a fluid sim turns into the shape of the domain, it is simply because there is no fluid in the domain.

The easy way to see this is to have an inflow object that starts a few frames into the animation. So yes, keyframing visibility is the right way to go, but if there is no fluid in the domain, increasing the resolution is not going to change anything. And yes, I know that is not what you said, but I thought it should be made clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works fine now! Your answers were very detailed and understandable!